# Php/HTML/css: links not clickable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

EDIT: Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d21jgqba/1/

I have some code where I am trying to link a different location but the links do not redirect me but have the correct webpage in the bottom left of the page when I hover over them. All help will be greatly appreciated!

I am using a expandable list code I found online but have edited to my own needs, both dont work for linking. The original code is given here: http://jasalguero.com/ledld/development/web/expandable-list/

Here are my edits:

The actual link is in the second while loop.

php:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="title"><h3>Courses</h3></div>
    <div id="listContainer">
        <div class="listControl">
            <a id="expandList">Expand All</a>
            <a id="collapseList">Collapse All</a>
        </div>
        <ul id="expList">
        <?php
            while($dept = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo"<li>".$dept['dname']."<ul>";

                $coursequery = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE dname='".$dept['dname']."'";
                $resultc = mysqli_query($mysqli, $coursequery) or die(mysql_error());

                while($course = mysqli_fetch_array($resultc)) {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"http://www.reddit.com/\">".$dept['dname']." ".$course['courseNO']."</a></li>";
                }

                echo "</ul></li>";
            }
            //echo "<li><a href=\"documents/".$dept['dname']."/".$course['courseNO']."/index.php\">".$dept['dname']." ".$course['courseNO']."</a></li>";
        ?>  
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
```

css:

```css
/********************/

/* GENERAL SETTINGS */

/********************/

body {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/********************/

/* EXPANDABLE LIST  */

/********************/

#listContainer {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#expList ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#expList p {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
#expList p:hover {
  background-color: #121212;
}
#expList li {
  line-height: 140%;
  text-indent: 0px;
  background-position: 1px 8px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* Collapsed state for list element */

#expList .collapsed {
  background-image: url(../img/collapsed.png);
}
/* Expanded state for list element
/* NOTE: This class must be located UNDER the collapsed one */

#expList .expanded {
  background-image: url(../img/expanded.png);
}
#expList {
  clear: both;
}
.listControl {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.listControl a {
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  color: #555555;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
.listControl a:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Generated HTML:

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Demo Expandable list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js">
  </script>
  </script>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Courses</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="listContainer">
    <div class="listControl">
      <a id="expandList">Expand All</a>
      <a id="collapseList">Collapse All</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="expList">
      <li>BSEN
        <ul></ul>
      </li>
      <li>CPSC
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/XboxOne">CPSC 413</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/XboxOne">CPSC 310</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>ENGG
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/XboxOne">ENGG 499</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (script.js):

```js
/**************************************************************/
/* Prepares the cv to be dynamically expandable/collapsible   */
/**************************************************************/
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click(function(event) {
      if (this == event.target) {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
      }
      return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed')
    .children('ul').hide();

  //Create the button funtionality
  $('#expandList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function() {
      $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
      $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
    })
  $('#collapseList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function() {
      $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
      $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
    })

};


/**************************************************************/
/* Functions to execute on loading the document               */
/**************************************************************/
$(document).ready(function() {
  prepareList()
});
```

Comment: instead of escaping your quotes, use separate single and double quotes, ie. "<a href='address'>" makes it a bit more readable.

Comment: Can you post the generated html code from the browser?

Comment: It seems that you're setting [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on all `<li>` elements.

Comment: I added the generated html code, thanks for the suggestion. The generated output has different links as it was a test page but is much cleaner then the original page I am working on. @GVashist

Comment: Can you post the javascript too?

Comment: Yeah, the PHP isn't necessary. I do wonder if the `pointer-events: none` is the culprit, like GVashist pointed out. Also, in this situation, I would recommend putting your code in a jsFiddle so we can play with the code a bit to see what the problem is. SO Snippets don't let you do that.

Comment: Note that the links in your "generated html" snippet work as there is no CSS applied. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values): `pointer-events:none` = "The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements *if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value.*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Straight off the bat, there are some HTML validation issues [div needs to be in a body tag, you have a missing <script> tag]. Its probably not the underlying issue, but often the smallest things come back to haunt you.

Comment: I am working on a better php, the generated one was one I quickly mocked up. I'm working on it for a second to make it work inside jsfiddle. I added the pointer-events:none myself and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It prevents click-ability for me. Links no longer work when I add `pointer-events:none` to quid's *working* example: http://jsfiddle.net/5kwe547e/1/

Comment: @showdev Added the jfiddle without the pointer-events:none http://jsfiddle.net/d21jgqba/1/

Links still doesnt work when I am hosting within wampserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hd08gLax/

**I changed return false; to return true; on line 8.**

```
function prepareList() {
    $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
        .click(function (event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return true;
    })
        .addClass('collapsed')
        .children('ul').hide();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    prepareList();
});

//Create the button funtionality
$('#expandList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function () {
    $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
    $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
});
$('#collapseList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click(function () {
    $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
    $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
});
```

Comment: I took the exact code from that site I listed and just changed one of the <li> to <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/XboxOne">CPSC 413</a> </li> And it still doesnt link when hosted in wampserver. I can make a gif maybe if that would help.

Comment: @user3261795 Look at the fiddle.  Change line 8 to return true;  Return false was stopping the click event before it could send you to the link.  I added target="_new" to the a tags so they would work in the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didnt notice you changed it! Thanks, I've spent hours on this. Really appreciate everyones help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line inside the css tag "#expList ul, li"

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem, though it was a contributor

Comment: @quid pointer-events: none; Makes all the li items non-reactive to any mouse events such as dragging, hovering, clicking etc

Comment: I agree that it was a contributor to the problem (and I upvoted you), but his JS still prevented the click event from finishing.

Answer (score 0):

In a separate unrelated case,For me the cause was preventDefault()

$('a').click( function(e) {

```
   e.preventDefault();
```

});

I removed that and it worked.